# How to make torrent magnet url clickable in Markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I've this torrent magnet URL.

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:6d8ac116eef6829f3e756c4c12a62ebfac2ba4f5&dn=Spenser.Confidential.2020.720p.NF.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969
```

I tried

`[Get Torrent](magnet:?xt...)`

and

`<a href="magnet:?xt...">Get Torrent</a>`

But the markdown system not accepting it as a link. It shows `Get Torrent` as plain text.

So, How to make torrent magnet url clickable in Markdown ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @NickRogers Nope :(

Comment: Not sure if this is an option for you, but found a workaround to use a tinyurl instead

Comment: @NtokozoZwane Wow. that worked. You may add this as an answer.

Comment: Happy it worked out for you too =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to generate a [tinyurl](https://tinyurl.com/) for the magnet link and use that instead